# Flutter Streambuilder not updating listview

Tags: flutter, listview

i have an app that is not updating the list of cards when i add a new item.
I run out of ideas and came here searching for a little help .

The list code

```
class FermentableIngredient {
  final String name;
...

List<dynamic> beerIngredients = [];

Stream<List<dynamic>> getBeerIngredientsStream() async* {
  yield beerIngredients;
}
```

The stream and list code (Its that way cause i load different card types in that list)

```
StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                stream: getBeerIngredientsStream(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final beerIngredients = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: beerIngredients!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final ingredient = beerIngredients[index];
                        if (ingredient is FermentableIngredient) {
                          return IngredientCard(
                            ingredient: 'malt',
                            ingredientName: ingredient.name,
                            weight: double.parse(ingredient.weight),
                            unit: ingredient.unit,
                          );
                        } else if (ingredient is HopIngredient) {
                          return IngredientCard(
                            ingredient: 'hop',
                            ingredientName: ingredient.name,
                            weight: ingredient.weight,
                            unit: ingredient.unit,
                          );
                        } else if (ingredient is OtherIngredient) {
                          return IngredientCard(
                            ingredient: 'other',
                            ingredientName: ingredient.name,
                            weight: ingredient.weight,
                            unit: ingredient.unit,
                          );
                        } else if (ingredient is YeastIngredient) {
                          return IngredientCard(
                            ingredient: 'yeast',
                            ingredientName: ingredient.name,
                            weight: ingredient.weight,
                            unit: ingredient.unit,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Container();
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),
```

The button to add new ingredients

```
MyButton(
                    label: 'Cadastrar\nFermentável',
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        FermentableIngredient newFermentable =
                            FermentableIngredient(
                                name: fermentableName.text,
                                category: fermentables
                                    .where((e) =>
                                        e.name.toLowerCase() ==
                                        fermentableName.text.toLowerCase())
                                    .toList()
                                    .map((e) => e.category)
                                    .toString(),
                                type: fermentables
                                    .where((e) =>
                                        e.name.toLowerCase() ==
                                        fermentableName.text.toLowerCase())
                                    .toList()
                                    .map((e) => e.type)
                                    .toString(),
                                color: fermentables
                                    .where((e) =>
                                        e.name.toLowerCase() ==
                                        fermentableName.text.toLowerCase())
                                    .toList()
                                    .map((e) => e.color)
                                    .toString(),
                                ppg: fermentables
                                    .where((e) =>
                                        e.name.toLowerCase() ==
                                        fermentableName.text.toLowerCase())
                                    .toList()
                                    .map((e) => e.ppg)
                                    .toString(),
                                weight: fermentableQuantity.text,
                                unit: selectedMaltUnit.toString());
                        addNewIngredient(newFermentable);
                        Get.back();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

The method to add

```
  void addNewIngredient(dynamic newIngredient) {
    setState(() {
      beerIngredients.add(newIngredient);
    });
    _beerIngredientsController.sink.add(beerIngredients);
  }
```

I already tried some of the options to ensure that the list update, but with no success, its storing in the list, but not update when i call the method to get back to the page of the list, if i go to the code and hit ctrl+s, the new card appears.

Comment: `stream: getBeerIngredientsStream()` Don't build the stream as the stream: parameter in StreamBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: Did not solve the problem =/

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you're just following the wrong approach to do it, with this:

```
Stream<List<dynamic>> getBeerIngredientsStream() async* {
  yield beerIngredients;
}
```

you're simply creating a `Stream` that will have a sinked value which is `beerIngredients` at this point, which equals to `[]`, and that's it, the Stream will be done.

I believe, what you're looking for is using the `StreamController` and managing the state with it (which is used in the BloC library), you need to create one:

```
final getBeerIngredientsStream = StreamController<List<dynamic>>();
```

then in the `StreamBuilder`, you will need to use the stream associated with the controller:

```
StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            stream: getBeerIngredientsStream.stream,
// ...
```

and then whenever you do `sink` a new `List<dynamic>` to the stream with:

```
getBeerIngredientsStream.sink.add(// REPLACE THIS WITH TH LIST)
```

the `getBeerIngredientsStream.stream` will trigger a new value and then updates the `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: Did not solve the problem, i also change for only listview.builder to make some tests, and still nothing